# Most pythonic way to get output from a shell command

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, python-2.x

I'm writing my first python program and I want to run a shell command and get the output. I want to do it in the cleanest possible / most pythonic way. This is what I've got atm.
Note: I also want to raise an Exception when there went something worng with execution of the shell command.

```
def lsCommand():
    process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out , err = process.communicate()
    returnc = process.returncode
    if returnc != 0:
        raise Exception(err)
    else:
        return out
```

What I discovered, is that when I remove the line **out , err = process.communicate()**, and replace it with time.sleep(4) (<= the ls command doesn't take 4 seconds to complete), The returncode is None, which means that it the subprocess isn't fnished yet. How is this possible? Does the **out , err = process.communicate()** do an implicit wait() methode call?

```
def lsCommand():
    process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    time.sleep(4)
    returnc = process.returncode
    if returnc != 0:
        print returnc
        raise Exception(err)
    else:
        return out
```

EDIT: I'm using python 2.7

I want to do a longer command **sudo find  "/media/usb0"  -type f -name "*.JPG" | wc -l**, but i'm not sure how to call it with Popen, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `communicate` implies `wait`; it reads the process' `stdout` and `stderr` until they are closed.

In the second example you `PIPE` the output of the `ls`; the child process `ls` is blocked writing to `stdout` and `stderr` until you read from the pipe - thus it would not completed within 4 seconds, or even 4 years until these descriptors are read. However, as polling the descriptors manually is prone to errors, the `Popen` class has the `communicate` method to avoid the pitfalls.

---

For a very pythonic way to easily get the output of a command, see [Popen.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) available since Python 3.1, and 2.7, though it does not raise an exception with the contents of `stderr` on failure. Your first example is good if you need the exception to contain the contents of stderr as a message.

---

To call the full pipeline in Python, you can use the `shell=True` with the full pipeline as a command.

```
pipeline = subprocess.Popen(
    'sudo find "/media/usb0" -type f -name "*.JPG" | wc -l',
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

However, you can also use `Popen`s to [make the pipeline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline):

```
find = subprocess.Popen(
    ['sudo', 'find', '/media/usb0', '-type', 'f', '-name', '*.JPG'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
wc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['wc', '-l'],
    stdin=find.stdout,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
find.stdout.close()
wc.communicate()
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, should have said that. Sorry. I will edit my question

Comment: I've read about thet check_output, I tried to use it but it didn't work, will try it again. Thanks. Do you happen to know how to use it with a longer command like the sudo find ... in my first post?

Comment: Is this more pythonic, if I don't care about err message?: def lsCommand():
  process = subprocess.check_output(['ls','-l'])
  return process

Comment: As I understand, the find example you gave at the end of the post, can't be done with the check_output methode because you're using stdout=subprocess.PIPE and this can cause deadlocks according to the documentation. Am I right?

Comment: ah, you `wc.communicate()`

Answer (score 1):

It will not call `time.sleep`, it will wait till the command complete its execution, it might be 4 second or more.

When you call `process.communicate()` it will actual make call to command and set the values in `process.returncode`.

If you will not call `process.communicate()` then default value of `process.returncode` is `None` and what its return when you replace `process.communicate()` with `time.sleep(4)`.

[Popen.returncode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode)

The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (**and indirectly by communicate()**). A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.

A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only).

Comment: If its solve your problem, select it as answer

Comment: it partially solves the question, but I'm still wondering if this is the cleanest code to write on python 2.7 to get the output from a shell command. Or are there any cleaner ways?